# map name across levels

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, json.net

I have this json

```
{
    "query":{
        "allcategories":{
           "accontinue":"!!!_songs"
        }
    }
}
```

here are the c# classes:

```
public class Allcategories
{
    public string accontinue { get; set; }
}
public class Query
{
    public Allcategories allcategories { get; set; }
}
public class RootObject
{
    public Query query { get; set; }
}
```

can i map this somehow the following C# classes? I want to skip one level, and reduce nesting of json like this:

```
public class Query
{  
    [JsonAttribute("allcategories.accontinue")]
    public string accontinue { get; set; }
}
public class RootObject
{
    public Query query { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Yes you can write a *JsonConverter*, but I don't think it will be useful for this simple assignment.

Comment: no simple solution like i suggested with Attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suggested code is valid and would reduce nesting, but `accontinue`would no longer be an `Allcategories` object, it would be a string attribute of `Query`.